# How to set description when creating a windows service with CreateService winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using the `CreateService` winapi call to create a windows service in C/C++. The API is described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx and works just fine.

However, I would like to add a description to the service so that it is displayed accordingly in the Services app. Tried to set the lpDisplayName but that corresponds to the Name field and not the description field in the services app.

How can I add a description to a service once it has been created? Thanks!

Comment: The documentation you linked explicitly states how to do this. In the "Remarks" section "Description Description specified by ChangeServiceConfig2 ." Follow that link and get info on how to do it "SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION
1
The lpInfo parameter is a pointer to a SERVICE_DESCRIPTION structure.".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the [ChangeServiceConfig2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988(v=vs.85).aspx) function with the [`SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685156(v=vs.85).aspx) option.

Comment: Thanks! That did it.